Combination of geometry nodes to produce chaos terrain
Chaos terrain, in the astronomical sense, is terrain which has been chopped up by tectonic forces, forming what's best described as "a mess". From orbit, it looks like a assortment of lines overlaying one another at random angles.
What combination of geometry nodes and/or modifiers could I use to sculpt a plane into something looking like that — specifically, the chaos terrain of Europa's Conamara Chaos?

Just a confirmation: do you want to mesh such a configuration, for example for a very close rendering ? Or do you want to render (from orbit ?) such a surface ? In the second case, a Shader could be easier and less expensive.

@StefLAncien I specifically want to deform a mesh into that kind of configuration. It doesn't have to be based off any real-life example; I'm just looking for a way to generate the same sort of fractured terrain.
